# Combining data parsed from within the same hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to combine large data sets that I've filtered out from a single hash. I've tried various things such as merge, but don't seem to be able to get the data to combine the way I'm envisioning. Here are the things I'm trying to combine:

```
puts '','=========GET INFO'
print_data = targetprocess.comments_with_ids #get the hash
puts print_data #show the hash for verification

puts '','=========GET IDs'
story_ids = print_data['Comments']['Comment'].map {|entry| entry['General']} #filter for story ids and story name
puts story_ids

puts '','=========GET COMMENTS'
comment_description = print_data['Comments']['Comment'].map {|words| words['Description']} #get all comments, these are in the same order as the story ids
puts comment_description
```

Ultimately what I would like it to look like is:

```
story_id 1 + comment_description 1

story_id 2 + comment_description 2
```

etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want; the first element of the array story_id + first element of comments_description array?

Comment: It's currently a hash, but either format is fine for my purposes. As long as I can iterate through all the data that's returned and pair them up with the same element position from the other data set.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing that the hash had some other nested structures I could use. In this example I use a nested hash, then store it as an array (I ultimately need this for other work) and then output.

```
puts '','=========GET INFO'
print_data = targetprocess.comments_with_ids #get the hash
puts print_data #show the hash for verification
puts '=========COMPLETE', ''

#=========HASH OF USEFUL DATA
results = {}
print_data['Comments']['Comment'].each{|entry|
  results[entry['Id'].chomp] = {:parent_id => entry['General']['Id'].chomp, :description => entry['Description'].chomp}}

#=========STORE HASH AS AN ARRAY
csv_array = []
results.each{|key,value|
  csv_array << [key, value[:parent_id], value[:description]]
  #=======FRIENDLY OUTPUT
  puts "Story_Id #{value[:parent_id]}, Comment_Id #{key}, Comment #{value[:description]}"}
```